# Can someone explain what the C# "Func<T,T>" does?

Tags: c#, func

I'm reading the Pro MVC 2 book, and there is an example of creating an extension method for the HtmlHelper class.

Here the code example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int,string> pageUrl)
{
    //Magic here.
}
```

And here is an example usage:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Generate_Links_To_Other_Pages()
{
    //Arrange: We're going to extend the Html helper class.
    //It doesn't matter if the variable we use is null            
    HtmlHelper html = null;

    PagingInfo pagingInfo = PagingInfo(){
        CurrentPage = 2,
        TotalItems = 28,
        ItemsPerPage = 10
    };

    Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;

    //Act: Here's how it should format the links.
    MvcHtmlString result = html.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrl);

    //Assert:
    result.ToString().ShouldEqual(@"<a href=""Page1"">1</a><a href=""Page2"">2</a><a href=""Page3"">3</a>")           

}
```

Edit: Removed part that confused the **point** of this question.

The question is: Why is the example using Func? When should I use it? What is Func?

Thanks!

Comment: Mainly, I'd like to know what the Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page1" + i; line is doing.

Comment: I don't understand. `Func<T, T>` has nothing to do with extension methods. What are you asking?

Comment: You mean the declaration of `PageLinks`? The first parameter is `this`, i.e. it is an extension method. That parameter gets bound to the `html` object in the call.

Comment: **NOTE**: Please disregard the extension method bit, I wrote the wrong question. I mainly want to learn about what Func is, and why this example chose to use it. Also, when I should use it. I provided the example, only for context purposes.

Comment: Note: The reference to extension methods is purely because in the MVC book Func is first used in the chapter which introduces them.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

A `Func<int, string>` like

```
Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;
```

is a delegate accepting `int` as its sole parameter and returning a `string`. In this example, it accepts an `int` parameter with name `i` and returns the string `"Page" + i` which just concatenates a standard string representation of `i` to the string `"Page"`.

In general, `Func<TSource, TResult>` accepts one parameter that is of type `TSource` and returns a parameter of type `TResult`. For example,

```
Func<string, string> toUpper = s => s.ToUpper();
```

then you can say

```
string upper = toUpper("hello, world!");
```

or

```
Func<DateTime, int> month = d => d.Month;
```

so you can say

```
int m = month(new DateTime(3, 15, 2011));
```

Answer (score 13):

`Func<int, String>` means a callback method that takes an `int` parameter and returns a `String` as the result.

The following expression, which is known as a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;
```

expands to something like this:

```
Func<int, String> pageUrl = delegate(int i)
{
    return "Page" + i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Func<int, string>` line that you are inquiring about is known as a lambda expression.

```
Func<int, String> pageUrl = i => "Page" + i;
```

This line can be described as a function that takes an int parameter (`i`) and returns a string `"Page" + i`;

It can be re-written as:

```
delegate(int i)
{
    return "Page" + i;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to overload delegates, say if the input was a generic T where T : class?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `PageLinks` method is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

In extension method, the first parameter starts with this keyword to indicate that it is an Extension method on the type represented by the first parameter.

The `Func<T1, T2>` is a delegate which represents a transformation from type `T1` to type `T2`. So basically, your `PageLinks` method will apply that transformation to `int` to produce a `string`.

Comment: Ok - but what about the Func part?

Comment: See my answer for link to Func.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<T, TResult>`: Encapsulates a method that has one parameter and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter. [See this page for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) and examples. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a blog post on this. Using `Func` you can resolve some of functional discrepancy. Read [here](http://nazmoonnoor.com/uses-func-in-cs/).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a where() extension method using Func please have a look...

```
public static IEnumerable<Tsource> Where<Tsource> ( this IEnumerable<Tsource> a , Func<Tsource , bool> Method )
{

    foreach ( var data in a )
    {
        //If the lambda Expression(delegate) returns "true" Then return the Data. (use 'yield' for deferred return)
        if ( Method.Invoke ( data ) )
        {
            yield return data;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like,

```
        foreach ( var item in Emps.Where ( e => e.Name == "Shiv" ).Select ( e1 => e1.Name ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine ( item );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own

```
Func<int,string> myfunc;
```

then right click Func to view definition. You will see it is a delegate underneith

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);
```