# Calling a method with doasync task

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I can't figure out how to call last part of this method:

```
private static async Task ForEachFileAsync(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, Func<string, Task> doAsync)
{
    // Avoid blocking the caller for the initial enumerate call.
    await Task.Yield();

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption))
    {
        await doAsync(file);
    }
}
```

This is what i have managed to do so far:

```
private void Stats_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ForEachFileAsync(@"E:\Path", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, what to put here? );
}
```

I Did not need an explanation of how System.Func works!! I only needed to know how to make a method call using  System.Func which WAS NOT found at "[Can someone explain what the C# "Func<T,T>" does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315500/can-someone-explain-what-the-c-sharp-funct-t-does)".

Adriani6 answer was the best and most helpful. Thanks

Comment: No! That question explains func T and there isn't a single example of method call usage since that's what I needed at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass a delegate to that method which accepts a string and returns a Task.. taken from the signature `System.Func<in T, out TResult>`

```
private static Task DoSomething(string task)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And you would put that reference to that method..

```
ForEachFileAsync(@"E:\Path", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, (str) => DoSomething(str));
```

You obviously don't want `throw new NotImplementedException();` in the body of `DoSomething`... you want to implement your own method.

Comment: Thank you the example and explanation !

Comment: I'd appreciate some feedback for the down-vote rather than just leaving a negative and keeping feedback to yourself, that doesn't help anyone.

Comment: That wasn't me! But you're right.. I am sure the same guy that down voted your answer also down voted my question lol! Your answer was the most helpful so thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `async (file) => /*perform async operation*/`

---

As described on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.2), a Func (Function) is used for specifying a method.

It's very similar to the way Action works, exception Actions returns Void, whereas Functions returns the last generic parameter. For example:

`Func<int, int, string>`
Would take the following method as an argument:

```
string AddNumbers(int value1, int value2)
{
    return (value1 + value2).ToString()
}
```

In the case of a Task, due to syntactic sugar implemented along with Tasks, you can perform the Await operations in a method marked as Async. For example:

`Func<string, Task>`
Would take the following method as an argument:

```
async Task AddNumbers(string url)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    await client.PostAsync(url);
}
```

---

Lamda expressions are shorthands for inline methods. So `async (url) => await new HttpClient().PostAsync(url);` is the same as the method written above.

In this case you'll probably just want to execute some asynchronous read/write operation on your hard drive.

Comment: `async void AddNumbers` why do you use `void`? it is a very bad practise

Comment: That is very true, my bad! I did indeed mean to write async Task, it has been corrected.

Comment: Thank you! I have many async void to replace here lol Thanks for pointing it out guys!